# How can I delegate JAAS authorization checks to Shiro?

Tags: java, authorization, authentication, jaas, shiro

I'm developing a server-side application that needs authentication and authorization based on objects. I like Shiro's simplicity, but for being compatible with JAAS, I wrote a LoginModule that uses Apache Shiro as the underlying mechanism.

But my problem is that I couldn't find a way to delegate JAAS authorization checks to Shiro. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Deniz, Did you find a way to use Shiro with JAAS? If not, what approach did you take? Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: My main concern was to use Shiro for JMX security, which is using JAAS as the primary security method. I solved this by implementing a JMXAuthenticator which creates an mutable JAAS subject on the curent access control context and stores the Shiro subject in the JAAS subject's private credentials set. Later on, I implemented a LoginModule which was actually a wrapper around the Shiro's Authenticator interface (extended by SecurityManagers).

Comment: Perhaps you could provide more information about exactly what is the problem, including the code of your LoginModule, what error you get, and the runtime configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note: The answer addresses the general case where an external authorization system is to be integrated with the JVM, by means of the standard security framework. It is not Shiro- or JMX-specific, as I am familiar with neither.

---

Conceptually, it appears that you are after the policy decision point (PDP) -- the facility where authorization queries (*"is entity X allowed to do Y?"*) are evaluated, that is. The JDK offers several of these:

1. The effective [`SecurityManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html), specifically its `checkXXX` group of methods.
2. The [`ProtectionDomain`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/ProtectionDomain.html) class, particularly its `implies(Permission)` method.
3. The key `implies(ProtectionDomain, Permission)` method of the effective [`Policy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/Policy.html).
4. Secondarily, the `implies` methods of [`CodeSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/CodeSource.html), [`PermissionCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/PermissionCollection.html), [`Permission`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/Permission.html), and [`Principal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/Principal.html).

Any of the aforementioned methods may be overridden in order to customize, at ascending granularity, the functionality of the conceptual PDP. It should be noted that JAAS did (contrary to what its name suggests) not really bring its own PDP along; rather, it provided the [means](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/security/auth/SubjectDomainCombiner.html) for the domain and policy to support principal-based queries, in addition to the original trust factor of code origin. Hence, to my eye, your requirement of remaining "JAAS-compatible" basically translates to wanting to use the (original-plus-JAAS) Java SE authorization model, a.k.a. *the* sandbox, which I doubt to be what you desire. Frameworks such as Shiro tend to be employed when the standard model is deemed either too low-level and/or performance-intensive; in other words, when authorization logic *need not* evaluate every single stack frame for a given set of trust factors, due to those factors being more frequently context-insensitive than not. Depending on the validity of my assumption, three main cases arise for examination:

1. Authorization is `AccessControlContext`-independent. Shiro-native authorization attributes (SNAAs), whatever they are, apply to the entire thread. Code origin is irrelevant.
2. Code origin matters, mandating use of the sandbox. SNAAs are still `AccessControlContext`-independent.
3. Code origin and SNAAs are both relevant and `AccessControlContext`-*dependent*.

---

#### 1. Authorization based solely on SNAAs

1. Manage authentication however you see fit. If you wish to continue using JAAS' `javax.security.auth` SPI for authentication, forget about establishing a standard `Subject` as the authentication outcome, instead directly tying the Shiro-specific one to thread-local storage. This way you get more convenient access to the SNAAs, and avoid having to use `AccessControlContext` (and suffer the potential [performance penalty](http://word-bits.flurg.com/jaas-is-terrible-and-there-is-no-escape-from-it/)), for their retrieval.
2. Subclass `SecurityManager`, overriding at least the two `checkPermission` methods such that they

   1. translate, if necessary, the `Permission` argument into something Shiro's PDP (SPDP) understands, prior to
   2. delegating to the SPDP with the thread-local SNAAs and permission (and throwing a `SecurityException` should the SPDP signal access denial).

   The security context-receiving overload may simply disregard the corresponding argument. At application initialization time, instantiate and install (`System::setSecurityManager`) your implementation.

---

#### 2. Hybrid authorization, combining code origin with context-insensitive SNAAs

1. Manage authentication however you see fit; once again associate the Shiro-specific `Subject` with the thread itself.
2. Subclass `SecurityManager`, overriding at least the two `checkPermission` methods, this time around such that they delegate to both the SPDP and/or the overridden implementation (which in turn calls `checkPermission` on, accordingly, the current or supplied access control context). Which one(s) and in what order should be consulted for any given permission is of course implementation-dependent. When both are to be invoked, the SPDP should be queried first, since it will likely respond faster than the access control context.
3. If the SPDP is to additionally handle evaluation of permissions granted to code originating from a certain location and/or set of code signers, you will also have to subclass `Policy`, implementing `implies(ProtectionDomain, Permission)` such that, like `SecurityManager::checkPermission` above, it passes some intelligible representation of the domain (typically only its `CodeSource`) and permission arguments -- but logically *not* the SNAAs -- to the SPDP. The implementation should be efficient to the extent possible, since it will be invoked once per domain per access control context at `checkPermission` time. Instantiate and install (`Policy::setPolicy`) your implementation.

---

#### 3. Hybrid authorization, combining code origin with SNAAs, both context-sensitive

1. Manage authentication however you see fit. Unfortunately the subject handling part is not as trivial as creating a `ThreadLocal` in this case.
2. Subclass, instantiate, and install a `Policy` that performs the combined duties of `SecurityManager::checkPermission` and `Policy::implies`, as individually described in the second case.
3. Instantiate and install a standard `SecurityManager`.
4. Create a `ProtectionDomain` subclass, capable of storing and exposing the SNAAs.
5. Author<sup>1</sup> a [`DomainCombiner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/security/DomainCombiner.html) that

   1. is constructed with the SNAAs;
   2. implements `combine(ProtectionDomain[], ProtectionDomain[])` such that

      1. it replaces the first (the "current" context) array argument's domains with equivalent instances of the custom implementation;
      2. then appends the second (the "assigned" or "inherited" context) argument's ones, if any, to the former as-is; and lastly
      3. returns the concatenation.

   Like `Policy::implies`, the implementation should be efficient (e.g. by eliminating duplicates), as it will be invoked every time the `getContext` and `checkPermission` `AccessController` methods are.
6. Upon successful authentication, create a new `AccessControlContext` that wraps the current one, along with an instance of the custom `DomainCombiner`, in turn wrapping the SNAAs. Wrap code to be executed beyond
   that point "within" an `AccessController::doPrivilegedWithCombiner` invocation, also passing along the replacement access control context.

---

<sub>1    Instead of using custom domains and your own combiner implementation, there is also the seemingly simpler alternative of translating the SNAAs into `Principal`s and, using the standard `SubjectDomainCombiner`, binding them to the current `AccessControlContext`'s domains (as above, or simply via `Subject::doAs`). Whether this approach reduces the policy's efficiency depends primarily on the call stack's depth (how many distinct domains the access control context comprises). Eventually the caching optimizations you thought you could avoid implementing as part of the domain combiner will hit you back when authoring the policy, so this is essentially a design decision you will have to make at that point.</sub>

Comment: Although I found a solution and answered my own question 6 years ago, the useful amount of information you provided here for all who stumbles upon this question definitely deserves to be an accepted answer.